# Find Imported Python Modules

Tags: python, flask

I'm building a flask application and I want to remove the redundancy on importing modules. So, on runtime I want to print all the imported modules.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to reduce? you can get a list of imported modules by examining `sys.modules`...

Comment: I moved some code between modules, but I haven't removed the the imports. So, I want to remove all the uneeded. I just don't need the import calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sys.modules.keys()` but you will need to import `sys` to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
print(sys.modules.keys())
```

Answer (score 1):

`sys.modules`

[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules)

"This is a dictionary that maps module names to modules which have already been loaded."